# ID short story about alternative wealth distribution

Tags: story-identification

I read a short story in the late 90s or early 2000s that was set in the future. The main characters were in a family, and they lived in an opulent and expensive home. They had lots to eat and every luxury. But, it slowly becomes clear, they are embarrassed about their wealth.

Finally, the other shoe drops and it's revealed that the highest status members of society have almost no possessions, and live extremely simple lives, while the lowest status members receive all the wealth from the high status, and live in luxury, mansions etc.

Comment: OP indicated in comments that it was a dupe.